# NullPointerException is thrown when a user control's button is clicked at clicked(this ,e)

Tags: c#, winforms

In this code, Form1 supposes to listen to the Add button in user control and displays the message in the Form1. When i run it in a debugging mode, it return NullPointerReference at clicked(this,e). Can someone help me with this? thanks.

User Control:

```
public event EventHandler clicked;

public DataInput()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Add.Click+= new EventHandler(Add_Click);
}

private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   items = textBox1.Text.PadRight(15) + textBox2.Text.PadRight(15) + textBox3.Text.PadRight(15);
   clicked(this, e);
}
```

Form:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dataInput.clicked+= new EventHandler(OnChanged);
}

public void OnChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("testing");
}
```

Comment: Never heard of a NullPointerReference :) Seriously, does the exception occur inside of clicked or *at* clicked? How is clicked defined?

Comment: -1 for nonsense exception name

Comment: Sorry about that, it called NullReferenceException, thrown at clicked(this,e);

Answer (score 4):

Exception is thrown because there are no subscriptions to your `clicked` event. Either Form1 is no yet created, maybe you're using different constructor, or you unsubscribed later.
Anyway, you should always check for subscription before invoking an event delegate.
Change your code in `Add_Click` to:

```
EventHandler evnt = clicked;
if (evnt != null)
    evnt(this, e);
```

Comment: It is working without throwing an exception. However, form1 cannot listen to the click. thanks

Comment: That is exactly why Exception was thrown. form1 didn't execute code to subscribe to event (`dataInput.clicked+= new EventHandler(OnChanged);`)

Answer (score 2):

not sure why the "clicked" EventHandler is null.
You should always make sure the EventHandler has been initialized before using.
i.e.

```
if(clicked != null)
{
    clicked(this, e);
}
```